# Octave: How should I go about having global constants handy for any program?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, octave, workspace

I would like to have a list of constants readily available to use in any script or function I write. For example, I have been defining constants like hbar (Planck's constant) at the start of any script that will be using it.

Instead of that, should I:

1. make a list of constants in a script and load that script every time
   I want to use it,
2. or save constants in a workspace and load that,
3. or is it possible for me to have global variables that will be there even when I close and reopen Octave,
4. or something else?

Comment: I use the `+` folders to package simple classes containing my constants. It only takes one line to call them up from a program. Read the documentation to learn more: [Packages Create Namespaces](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html)

Comment: Don't have global constants. Instead, create functions that return those constants. For example, Octave does not have variables for `pi`, `e`, `Inf`, etc..., they are all functions.

Comment: @Hoki this would have been ideal if Octave could import the constants from the +Package, but unfortunately this is not implermented at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU Octave I would suggest using the miscellaneous package and the function `physical_constant` which already has [335 constants](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/miscellaneous/ci/default/tree/inst/physical_constant.m). In your case:

```
[val, uncertainty, unit] = physical_constant ("Planck constant over 2 pi")
val =    1.0546e-34
uncertainty =    4.7000e-42
unit = J s
```

If you want don't want this, then use functions, not global vars.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the physical_constant file and now I'm trying to change it where I don't need to type in the full name of the constant. Currently, if I'm one letter off it throws an error saying it wasn't found. I don't know how to make it more adaptable. For example, there's only ~2 constants that use "Planck" in it. Typing "Planck pi" should be enough to return hbar.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated, there are a few ways to solve this problem.  To address your third option, which seems to be closest to the spirit of what you want, you've got at least two ways of handling this.

1.) If the variables need to be mutable.  Create a function or script that initializes the variables to what you want them to be.  I'm going to reference the MATLAB documentation but it should basically be the same.

```
function initglobals()
  global the_answer
  the_answer = 42;
end
```

Then any time you want to use these globals in a script, you first indicate to Octave that you'll be using the variable as a global:

```
...
global the_answer
disp(the_answer) %prints 42
...
```

For this to be more useful, I'd recommend generating a startup script and putting in your `.octaverc` [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Startup-Files.html).  This startup script can call this function to initialize your globals.

2.) Your other choice, if the globals ought to be immutable (for example, a physics constant) is to define a function that returns the value you want.

```
function [out] = the_answer()
  out = 42;
end
```

Then you can simply just use `the_answer` to access your constant.

In both cases you'll want to add these functions to your path.  Create your collections of functions and put them somewhere, then add that location to your path. [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Manipulating-the-Load-Path.html)

Comment: I do like this answer, and I may implement your #2 choice. However, the other Andy provides a neat file that already has a lot of constants defined.